# Are there Tags that could solve this?

Tags: lottie, bodymovin

New to coding, trying to see what/if Tags would make this code work

So I'm a beginner with basic understanding and more of a Graphics/ Designer than code based.  I found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/WEDOO/pen/EQrOxV) by WEDOO that has exactly what I need and want to try to just swap my "animationData" to see if I can get it to work and then modify it as needed for my test (will be assign the button code to various objects for the SVG).  I Can't seem to find the right "Tags" or determine if its referencing an external script...I'd image it just needs the right information to function...is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: targetAnim,
  path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/914929/data-testo4.json...
```

My output from BodyMovin in a JSON file:

```
var animationData = 
  {"v":"5.4.2","fr":29.9700012207031,"ip":0,"op":149.000006068894...
```

Does it make sense to think that I need replace the `var animation` with info that should be the `targetAnim` with the code in the JSON file? So far put the `var animationData` breaks things and does nothing (visually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bodymovin.loadAnimation` can be passed either a URL to a Bodymovin JSON via the `path` option OR you can pass the animation JSON inline by setting the `animationData` option instead.

In you case it would end up looking something like:

```
var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: targetAnim,
  animationData = {"v":"5.4.2","fr":29.9700012207031,"ip":0,"op":149.000006068894...
...
})
```